# How to ask confirmation when move node in Angular UI Tree?

Tags: angularjs

How to ask confirmation when move node in Angular UI Tree?

When I move node across tree, how to ask confirmation (alert message)?

I tried to use callback `dragStop`

```
 <div data-ui-tree="treeOptions" id="tree-root">
```

And function is:

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
   $scope.treeOptions = {
            dragStop : function (e) {
                alert("ok");
            }
        };         
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [beforeDrop](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree#beforedropevent) event:

```
beforeDrop: function(ev) {
    return confirm("SHOULD DROP?!!");
}
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jvu8s5c1/)

Answer (score 0):

**beforeDrop(event)**

> The beforeDrop function is called before the dragging node is dropped.
>   If you implement this callback, the return value determines whether
>   the drop event is allowed to proceed.

It sholud be:

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
   beforeDrop : function (e) {
     return confirm("Are you sure?");
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the **beforeDrop** event. But even on clicking a node triggers the event, so you need somehow to identify a real change in your tree structure. So I used the code below.

Index comparison is for identifying the change inside the same parent and node is for moving to another parent.
You might wanna change the **.title** to whatever suits you best.

```
$scope.treeOptions = {
    beforeDrop : function (e) {

        if(e.source.index !== e.dest.index || 
            e.source.nodesScope.node.title !== e.dest.nodesScope.node.title) {
            return confirm("Are you sure?");
        }
        
    }
};
```